# rename the final according to my list input

Tags: python, list, loops

I would like to rename the file according to several examples.
My idea is by using a list such as(example):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10, 100, 200]
```

Then loop into this list and rename based on each of the element within the list.

My code is as follow (This is an example of the code and not the full version, I just want to get to know a way to input these element into the "**" and replace it with value such as "1", "2" or "100"):

```
class man:
    ...

def function(a):
    ...

def output1(myfile):
    with open("text_**.txt","w+") as outfile:
        outfile.write()

def output2(myfile2):
    with open("text_**.txt","w+") as outfile:
        outfile.write()

def total(a,b):
    with open("text_**.txt","w+") as outfile:
        outfile.write()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    file = function("**.txt")
    ...


    output1(myfile)
    output2(myfile2)
    total("**.txt", "**.txt")
```

For example, I would like my output to be like this:

```
class man:
    ...

def function(a):
    ...


def output1(myfile):
    with open("text_1.txt","w+") as outfile:
        outfile.write()

def output2(myfile2):
    with open("text_1.txt","w+") as outfile:
        outfile.write()

def total(a,b):
    with open("text_1.txt","w+") as outfile:
        outfile.write()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    file = function("1.txt")
    ...


    output1(myfile)
    output2(myfile2)
    total("1.txt", "1.txt")
```

My goal is the "**" will be replace with all the elements within the list from 1 to 200. If possible to make it this way then I wouldnt need to keep changing the value in my program everytime I want to load new name for it.

Comment: For an element i(=1) in a , `with open("text_" + str(i) + ".txt","w+") as outfile:`  will open text_1.txt file. Am I missing something here?

Comment: to complete @NihalSangeeth answer, I suggest using f-strings if you're using python3.6+, `with open(f"text_{counter_variable}.txt", "w+") as outfile:` it will be easier to read

Comment: Yes but how can I do it should I loop for the whole "if __name__ == "__main__":" by using for i in a? My program runs by manually inputing the number into "**" for example, when I change all to 1, then it will run the files for 1 and rename it. and input 2 then it will run files for 2 and rename it. until all the way to 200. If I do it manually, then I have to change all of it 200 times. Is there a good way of looping while not disturbing my program working functions? Because within "if __name__ == "__main__":", there is still some functions of looping so I am afraid it might clash

Comment: OOOOh, you want to change the value BETWEEN each script execution, am I right ?

Comment: Yes, every execution will have different values, that is what I want. Its like what you said, change between each script execution

Comment: @JJson Your usecase is still not clear. What do you mean by `Is there a good way of looping while not disturbing my program working functions?`

Answer (score 1):

Okay,

I suppose you could use an environment variable for this.

```
import os
counter = os.environ.get('MY_FILE_COUNTER')
if counter is None:
   os.environ['MY_FILE_COUNTER'] = 1
else:
   os.environ['MY_FILE_COUNTER'] += 1

# do your stuff
```

Or you could save the current value in a text file and load it up before processing your stuff

Comment: Yes, another way is to save the current 1 then load 2 and save 2 then load 3 and save 3 all the way until 200. Is the above solution works the same?

Comment: May I know what about the name for "**"? What should I put in there?

Comment: oh, you just need to pass the `counter` variable or even use the `os.environ.get("MY_FILE_COUNTER")` directly: like with `open(f"text_{os.environ.get("MY_FILE_COUNTER")}.txt", "w+").......`

EDIT: the f-string works only with python3.6+, if you're not using this see the first comment and replace the `str(i)`

Comment: I tried to change all but i received syntax error. I am using 3.6

Comment: Indeed, you need to change the quotes, I used the `"` both times, just replace a pair of them: `os.environ.get('MY_FILE_COUNTER')`